# memory grow on a pointer?

Tags: objective-c, c, xcode

I have a memory grow on a pointer, which i see in xcode instruments-allocations(iphone)

i have this : (audio buffer callback function that is perform **many times** a second )

```
int16_t *q = (int16_t *)(&bufferList)->mBuffers[0].mData;
int16_t average ;

for(int i=0; i < inNumberFrames; i++)
{
  average=q[i];  //comment this solve all.
```

If i comment the last line, it becomes ok. thats it. and obviously q[i] is a problem.
i cant figure out, what am i doing wrong with this line .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any specific issue that can cause memory growth in the snippet you posted:

- you are not allocating any kind of memory
- you are not retaining anything (since it's plain C)

So there is no way that any of the code in your question could cause a leak. Probably something is missing here.

Instruments should tell you which `malloc` or `new` caused the allocation that is leaking every time.

Comment: i know, but this is a fact, removing that line of code solve it. maybe overloading q can cause leaks ?

Comment: It's also a fact that instruments tell you which call to `malloc/new` is responsible for the leak.  Why not look at that information?

Comment: @n.m how do i see it ? i was looking for this for days.... it just shows so many lines with adresses that means nothing to me, and some objects names that i dont even know. can you direct me ?

Comment: Apparently I was talking off the top of my head. I am not familiar with xcode at all. The instruments *should* tell you which call to `malloc/new` is responsible for the leak, that would be a more accurate statement.

Answer (score 0):

what type is `mBuffers`?.  Is it possible that the `[]` is overloaded, and doing some allocation, or reference counting behind the scenes?    When you comment out the suspect line, the compiler may optimize out the whole assignment to `q`, avoiding the problem.

Comment: This could be true in an Objective-C++ environment. But I supposed he was just going plain Objective-C. Nice guess though!